# Method Issues: Will not return anything

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

Doing a project with Java ArrayLists where I have to make methods to perform certain things with the ArrayList. This one is supposed to add all the ArrayList values together and return the sum but for some reason it runs with no errors but does not return anything. How can I fix this problem and get sum to print/be returned?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayListofNums
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
ArrayList<Integer> nums;

nums = new ArrayList<Integer>( );

nums.add( new Integer(11) );
nums.add( new Integer(83) );
nums.add( new Integer(58) );
nums.add( new Integer(85) );
nums.add( new Integer(42) );
nums.add( new Integer(14) );
nums.add( new Integer(27) );
nums.add( new Integer(30) );
nums.add( new Integer(61) );
nums.add( new Integer(76) );
int sumofall;
}
public static int sumofall (ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
int sum = 0; 
for (int i : nums){
sum += i;
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: you didn't call the method `sumofall`, `int sumofall` is to declare variable having name as `sumofall` how can you expect it will return value?

Comment: Replace `int sumofall` with `int sum = sumofall(nums)`

Comment: change to `int sumofall = ArrayListofNums.sumofall(nums);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Your solution gave me the same problem I already have.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your solution also did not yield the sum being returned.

Comment: and what problem is that?  Maybe you should try adding some code that `prints` the value

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I made a System.out.println ("Sum is " + sum); to have it print

Comment: @ScaryWombat Just did that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try thisone:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class ArrayListofNums
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> nums;

        nums = new ArrayList<Integer>( );

        nums.add( new Integer(11) );
        nums.add( new Integer(83) );
        nums.add( new Integer(58) );
        nums.add( new Integer(85) );
        nums.add( new Integer(42) );
        nums.add( new Integer(14) );
        nums.add( new Integer(27) );
        nums.add( new Integer(30) );
        nums.add( new Integer(61) );
        nums.add( new Integer(76) );

        System.out.println(sumofall(nums));
    }


    public static int sumofall (ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
        int sum = 0; 
        for (int i : nums){
            sum += i;
        }
    return sum;
    }
}
```